# migrate error with Django 1.7 while adding new model

Tags: python, django

I created a new model names Join with three fields, email, timestamp and updated timestamp. But, the databse sync started giving me error to add default values to create table. I added some random values and now it has started giving me totally random errors beyond my understanding. Please help here.

Here's my model:

```
class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(default="default@default.com")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, default = "")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

And here's the error:

```
(learn_django) C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\source>python manage.py ma
kemigrations
Migrations for 'joins':
  0004_auto_20150320_2358.py:
    - Alter field timestamp on join
    - Alter field updated on join

(learn_django) C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\source>python manage.py mi
grate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, joins, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying joins.0002_auto_20150320_2346...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
agement\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
agement\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
agement\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
agement\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\man
agement\commands\migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migra
tions\executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migra
tions\executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migra
tions\migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, ne
w_state)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migra
tions\operations\fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\sqlite3\schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\sqlite3\schema.py", line 75, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\schema.py", line 188, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\fields\__init__.py", line 627, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\fields\__init__.py", line 1290, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\fields\__init__.py", line 1269, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\fields\__init__.py", line 1171, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\learn_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\fields\__init__.py", line 1252, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'00:00:00' value has an invalid forma
t. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

When Django asks "add default values to create table", you need to create values that resonate with the TYPE of that particular column.

Your error is apparent here:
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'00:00:00' value has an invalid            format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

The "random" values you entered must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.

Remove the DateTimeFields from the model, remigrate, and start over. This time, when you're asked to put in default values, put it a random 'datetime' (i.e. 2006-10-25 14:30:59).

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

Best,
aj